# Count with inner join

Tags: sql

I have been having problem counting my program.

My SQL query is:

```
select table_3.SERIAL, TABLE_3.ID, Table_3.OPERATOR, TABLE_1.PROGRAM, TABLE_1.COLOR, tABLE_1.PART_customer 
from table_3 
inner join table_1
    on Table_1.[SERIAL]=table_3.[SERIAL]
GROUP BY TABLE_3.SERIAL,TABLE_3.ID,TABLE_3.OPERATOR,TABLE_1.PROGRAM,Table_1.COLOR,Table_1.PART_customer
```

and my output is

```
Serial  id   operator   program       color     part_CUSTOMER   
104451  1       a1      GMT-172       Switch    23250063
104451  1       a1      GMT-177       Summit    23214845
104552  9       b1      GMT-172       Switch    23250063
104552  9       b1      GMT-177       Summit    23214845
104855  3       c1      GMT-172       Switch    23250063
104855  3       c1      GMT-177       Summit    23214845
```

I need to count them such a way that I should be obtained

```
Serial  id   operator   program       color     part_CUSTOMER      TOTAL
104451  1       a1      GMT-172       Switch    23250063             2
104552  9       b1      GMT-172       Switch    23250063             2
104855  3       c1      GMT-172       Switch    23250063             2
```

Comment: How are you determining what `program` and `color` are in the output?

Comment: are "table_1" and "table_3" temp tables? the summary of that data looks very arbitrary and I don't trust it. assuming they are temp tables I would go back further to verify they are created properly.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you don't really want `program` or `color` in the output.  As far as I can tell, you are choosing arbitrary values for them.

So, just aggregate by the values you need and add a count:

```
select t3.SERIAL, t3.ID, t1.operator, t1.PART_customer, COUNT(*)
from table_3 t3 inner join
     table_1 t1
     on t1.[SERIAL] = t3.[SERIAL]
group by t3.SERIAL, t3.ID, t1.operator, t1.PART_customer;
```

If you want `program` or `color` value, then you can use `MIN()` or `MAX()`, as appropriate.

EDIT:

Technically, you can get what you want by doing:

```
select t.*
from (select t3.SERIAL, t3.ID, t1.operator, t1.PROGRAM, t1.COLOR, t1.PART_customer,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITOIN BY t3.SERIAL, t3.ID, t1.operator, t1.PART_customer) as cnt
      from table_3 t3 inner join
           table_1 t1
           on t1.[SERIAL] = t3.[SERIAL]
     ) t
where program = 'GMT-172';
```

Comment: I think you mean `select t3.SERIAL, t3.ID, **t1.operator**, COUNT(*)` becaue `part_customer` also looks random